# Magento2 customer register event for rest call

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, event-observer, rest-api

I am sending sms on customer registration using `customer_register_success`, fired in

```
app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php
```

But as this is from controller, and not fired when user is created using restapi, is there any cleaner event which can suffice for web and restapi calls

Answer (score 0):

Customer registration event for rest API `customer_register_success` event not working.

I have used `customer_save_after` event and it is working fine in customer register rest API call.

Follow below file path to create custom module and call event in customer registration rest API call

> Filepath: magento/app/code/Vendor/CustomerRegister/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_CustomerRegister',
    __DIR__
);
```

> Filepath: magento/app/code/Vendor/CustomerRegister/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_CustomerRegister" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

> Filepath:
> magento/app/code/Vendor/CustomerRegister/etc/webapi_rest/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">   

    <event name="customer_save_after">
        <observer name="customer_resgister_observerAPI" instance="Vendor\CustomerRegister\Observer\CreatePostCustomer" />
    </event>

</config>
```

> Filepath:
> magento/app/code/Vendor/CustomerRegister/Observer/CreatePostCustomer.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\CustomerRegister\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as Observer;

class CreatePostCustomer implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $data = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        
        // Add custom logic here
        
    }
    
}
```

Hope it help!